# When do I have to use gerund with "to"?

Tags: grammar

I've seen some cases like

> "He want back to working"
>
> "He decided returned to playing soccer"
>
> "Mexico went from exporting just coffee and oil to exporting: cars,
>   tv, engines, laptops, etc.

Why ?

English teachers always say there are to options "to-infinitive" and gerund but I have never heard about a gerund with "to" before

Answer (score 1):

It's not a "to gerund". "To" is the preposition used with the verbs "go back", "return" and "go" to denote the destination (real or metaphorical). This "to" cannot be followed by an infinitive, so a following verb must be gerund.

Note the difference between:

> He went to see his friend.

"To" introduces a purpose clause, and takes the infinitive.

and

> He went back to stealing.

"To" introduces the destination of the (metaphorical) journey, and cannot be followed by an infinitive.